# Lua Splitting and Combining a String

Tags: nginx, lua

I want to shred and change the following file path with the match command.

I need to find the X123456 value and change it.

Old Path:

```
/data/documents/file_x123456_999.pdf
```

New Path:

```
/data/documents/file_CHANGED_999.pdf
```

how can i do this with lua?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gsub](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) function to do this: `path = path:gsub("_x123456_", "_CHANGED_")`

If the text you want to replace an unknown text at a known position or of known format replace `"_x123456_"` with an appropriate string [pattern](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1)

Comment: I can't use this as it's always variable (x123456)

Comment: @SweetNGX that's why Paul provided a link to the Lua manual which explains in detail how to use string.gsub. `"_x123456_` is a pattern and you can represent anything with it if you again read the manual and know how to use string patterns.